# Assigning multiple if statements in a sequential always block

Tags: verilog

Say I have two always blocks:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) a <= 0;
  else begin
     if (condition_one) a <= 1;
  end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) b <= 0;
  else begin
     if (condition_two) b <= 1;
  end
end
```

What would be the difference if I combine them into a single always block like below?

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
     a <= 0;
     b <= 0;
  end else begin
     if (condition_one) a <= 1;
     if (condition_two) b <= 1;
  end
end
```

And if I have more variables, such as c,d,e, etc., in addition to a and b, would a single `always` block have too much delay to process all these parallel independent `if` statements?
Is it safer to separate them into parallel `always` blocks?

Comment: Hi, I meant that everything inside the always is executed in order correct? If I have too many if statements, would it accumulate delay to execute the last if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both code samples should simulate the same way, regardless of how many variables you add.

Regarding your question about delays to process, simulations should take the same amount of time to execute for both cases.  Since Verilog code is compiled, both code samples should be compiled into effectively the same image.

It might be easier to understand and maintain the code if you use separate `always` blocks, especially as the number of variables increases.  For a small number of variables like your example, either is fine.